# How to update SQLITE3 version of Xcode?

Tags: xcode, sqlite

I already searched on the net a way to update the SQLITE3 version of Xcode, but I didn't found any working way. It is a way to do it?

Comment: Xcode doesn't have a version of sqlite.  OSX does though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your own version of sqlite3, perhaps because you want to use newer features only provided by a later version, then probably the best thing to do would be to create an Xcode static library project to build sqlite3 and then include that library with your app (statically linked).  This will avoid using the system version.

This should be fairly trivial, given the number of source files that make-up sqlite3.

You could probably make a dynamic library version, but that's slightly more complicated, though certainly possible.